# Apache2 Problems after updating OSX to High Sierra

Tags: apache, web, server, dns, apache2

For the week I have had major issues with Apache. My development environment on my mac stopped working after I updated to High Sierra. I tried for hours fixing this myself but couldn't find a solution.

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix)

Basically what is happening, whenever I try to restart apache I get this message:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully 
qualified domain name, using 10.0.0.50. Set the 'ServerName' directive 
globally to suppress this message
```

I have tried a ton of different ways of configuring my vhosts file as well as my httpd config but have seen no improvement.

The document root path was not pointed where my website existed before. After finding that out and pointing it at the correct location the "It Works!" message I was getting every-time disappeared and now I am only greeted with a message that says

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

This message happens no matter what path I put for the DocumentRoot section so I'm not sure what the real problem is.

Also, I have my apache set up to use localhost, however it continues to use 10.0.0.50 as it's IP of choice. I have never seen this IP before and I am confused on where it came from.

TLDR: I am having tons of problems with apache after updating to High Sierra, have tried to uninstall/reinstall. Apache is using 10.0.0.50 as the IP, DocumentRoot seems to have problems, config seems to be messed up.

Comment: After upgrading from Sierra to High Sierra I followed this super-helpful guide to get my "MAMP" environment back to working state: https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps It guides you through all the line edits needed to Apache's config files

Answer (score 1):

Check configuration:

```
httpd -t

AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.79. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

To fix that:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Before:

```
ServerName www.example.com:80
```

After:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Check configuration again:

```
httpd -t

Syntax OK
```